# Online story - mother tempted by youth leader, demonic possession involving a movie

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror, demons

I read this story online in the last five years or so. I think it's a long short story or possibly a novelette. The main character is a woman with two teenage sons. The sons go to scout or church meetings some evenings. The new leader of the scouts (or youth pastor at the church?) is charming, and the woman finds herself having disturbing fantasies about him, in spite of being happily married. One night, the woman is washing dishes (I think) and has a sudden premonition of disaster, and then gets word that her husband had died (in a car accident). Her sons react very oddly, seeming unaffected by the death of their father, and making accusations of infidelity. Somehow the woman realizes that there's demonic possession affecting her sons, and goes to the meeting hall to fight. Defeating the demon intermittently possessing her sons (and the youth leader?) involves destroying a movie that has been shown to the sons at one of their meetings.